# how to add background color for layer text field in mapbox-gl

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

how to add a background color for layer text-field in mapbox-gl.. or how it can be done so that there's background box on the text-field

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-15",
        "text-field": "{title}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
        "text-anchor": "top"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

While I also don't know how to draw a background box, we may be looking for the same thing which is to obscure any other text beneath the custom label so that it pops and is more legible. If so, I did discover that you can add a "halo" which will achieve the desired effect.

```
"layout": {
                "icon-image": symbol + "-15",
                "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                "text-field": symbol,
                "text-font": ["Open Sans Bold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
                "text-size": 11,
                "text-transform": "uppercase",
                "text-letter-spacing": 0.05,
                "text-offset": [0, 1.5]
            },
            "paint": {
                "text-color": "#202",
                "text-halo-color": "#fff",
                "text-halo-width": 2
            },
```

This was taken from [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers-by-input/) on their site.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I think many people would like to put up a text and make it stand out a little bit without putting in too much code. I tried it with text-halo-width: 5, and it gives a nice little white box around the text. Thanks man!

Comment: Is there a way of adding a padding around the text which would make the halo even bigger? The `halo-width` after the value 4 does not seem to change at all. I need bigger padding around the text

Answer (score 0):

This is several years late, but I was having the same issue and found Mapbox style "Mineral" by Madison Draper has this effect (labels have a bg color) - she set halo width to 30px, blur to 10px, and the result is a bg color (because Mapbox doesn't seem to handle the halo blur beyond "normal" amounts, and excessive halo width gets cropped out of the bounding box for the text.)

See this:
https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-the-mineral-map-style-cc47e5a980b6
Towards the bottom there is a link to duplicate this style

(Also) If you are setting this by code and not via the Studio:
Also note that since halo is a separate "Paint" property - be sure to see this as well:

[Mapbox GL JS: unknown property "text-halo-width" when other properties work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222629/mapbox-gl-js-unknown-property-text-halo-width-when-other-properties-work)