# Mapbox GL JS: unknown property "text-halo-width" when other properties work

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Using mapbox-gl 2.14.1, when I configure a layer for my map like this:

```js
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'labels-layer',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'source': 'labels-source',
            'layout': {
                'text-field': ['get', 'description'],
                'text-halo-width': 1,
                'text-font': ["Lato Bold"], 
                'text-size': 14,
                'text-max-width': 20,
                'text-variable-anchor': ['left', 'bottom', 'top', 'right'],
                'text-radial-offset': 0.5,
                'text-justify': 'auto'
            }
        });
```

I get an error: `Error: layers.labels-layer.layout.text-halo-width: unknown property "text-halo-width"`

[The property is documented on the website](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-text-halo-width), alongside all of the other `text-*` properties I'm using. If I remove that property, everything works fine. The other `text-halo-*` properties (not used in example above) also produce errors.

Is this a documentation problem? Or am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Upon closer reading of the documentation, I realized that `text-halo-width` and related properties are *paint* properties, not *layout* properties, and so need to be configured in a different place.

Specifically, this works:

```js
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'labels-layer',
            'type': 'symbol',
            'source': 'labels-source',
            'layout': {
                'text-field': ['get', 'description'],
                'text-font': ["Lato Bold"],
                'text-size': 14,
                'text-max-width': 20,
                'text-variable-anchor': ['left', 'bottom', 'top', 'right'],
                'text-radial-offset': 0.5,
                'text-justify': 'auto'
            },
            'paint': {
                'text-halo-width': 1,
                'text-halo-color': 'white'
            }
        });
```